# Put shiny widget as column header in dt::datable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Is there a way to add a shiny widget as the `selectInput()` here as a datatable column header in a way that the user will select from there which `Species` he wants and see the relative data.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
Species<-unique(iris$Species)
value<-c(5,6,7)
df<-data.frame(Species,value)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "My Chart"),
  dashboardSidebar(
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    selectInput("sel","Species",choices=unique(iris$Species),selected = unique(iris$Species)[1],multiple = F),
    dataTableOutput("table")
    
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) { 
  #Plot for Trace Explorer
  output$table<-renderDataTable(
    datatable(df)
  )
  
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

That functionality is built in datatable package. You can use the `filter` argument.

```
output$table<-renderDataTable(
    datatable(df,
              filter = "top")
  )
```

This will add a select dropdown for factor variables, and a regular input box for character variables.